# All Links and forms are going to 404 error page

Tags: zend-framework

In my project all links and form submission are goes to 404 error page, but i can see all pages in browser by typing direct URL in address bar, also the CSS and JS files are not affecting the pages, How to fix this issue?

Pls help me!!

Answer (score 0):

you might have to make sure your redirection are working ok. i.e.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ "/index.php" [NC,L]
```

Also if your project is not at the top of the webiste i.e. url like http://foobar.net/ you have to change the root and make sure the redirection include the directory. The best way to do that would to put the following code to an .htaccess in the public directory of your project.

I also advice you to take a look at the [quickstart guide](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart/create-your-project) for more information